# Group ionic 3 list by weekdays

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to make a list of parties grouped by weekdays. All of this data is JSON and each event has a timestamp.

I want to get display a list with headers like "Monday 10 September" with all events from that day and then "Tuesday 11 September" and so on. With those headers gotten from the timestamps.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you

EDIT: This is what each event in the JSON feed looks like.

```
{
"id": 39523,
"url": "***",
"title": "Cocktail Hour",
"content": "<p>All cocktails NAfl. 15.-</p> ",
"excerpt": [
    "Bartenders preparing unique cocktails with fresh & premium ingredients"
],

"tags": [],

"custom_fields": {
    "evcal_repeat": "yes",
    "evcal_srow": 1536800400,
    "evcal_erow": 1536804000,
    "evcal_lmlink": null,
    "evcal_subtitle": [
        "Bartenders preparing unique cocktails with fresh & premium ingredients"
    ],
    "featured": "no",
    "evcal_lat": "12.0889603",
    "evcal_lon": "-68.8992923"
},

"taxonomy_event_location": [{
    "id": 1666,
    "title": "Mood Beach",
    "slug": "***",
    "location_address": "***",
    "location_lat": "12.0889603",
    "location_lon": "-68.8992923"
}],

"taxonomy_event_type": [{
    "id": 1216,
    "title": "Club Nights"
}, {
    "id": 1175,
    "title": "Happy Hour"
}, {
    "id": 1831,
    "title": "Parties & Live Music"
}],

"attachments": [
    "***"
],
"mod": "July 20, 2018"
```

}

Comment: hey, can you privode example of the json feed with event?

Comment: Here it is, thank you.

Comment: Hey Luis, this is not a valid json format. Can you make sure you provide valid json? otherwise its hard to help you as one needs to fix data structures first. You can use https://jsoncompare.com/#!/simple/ or similar

Comment: Ok my bad, but now it's valid. evcal_srow means starting time by the way, that's what I want to use to group the events.

Comment: cool;) I will try to get you something;)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey @SergeyRudenko I somehow made it. I'm not sure about the performance on a real device so I'm still happy to look at your efforts.

Comment: Hey Luis, yes sorry I got distracted;/ Generally I wanted to share with you blitzstack with some approach rather than full implementation. Eager to see how you approached it. I wanted to do on the client transformation using .map to create new iterable (Array) with dates/dayofweeks as core property + another events property being an array for all the events we detected as belonging to the date.